# Extracting a specific number from a string using regex function in Spark SQL

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in mysql which has POST_ID and corresponding INTEREST:

[image]

I used following regular expression query to select interest containing 1,2,3.

```
SELECT * FROM INTEREST_POST where INTEREST REGEXP '(?=.*[[:<:]]1[[:>:]])(?=.*[[:<:]]3[[:>:]])(?=.*[[:<:]]2[[:>:]])';
```

I imported the table in HDFS. However, when I use the same query in SparkSQL, it shows null records.

How to use REGEXP function here in spark to select interest containing 1,2,3?

Answer (score 0):

The Regex you are using need to be changed a bit. You could do something like the following.

```
scala> val myDf2 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM INTEREST_POST where INTEREST REGEXP '^[1-3](,[1-3])*$'")
myDf2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [INTEREST_POST_ID: int, USER_POST_ID: int ... 1 more field]

scala> myDf2.show
+----------------+------------+--------+
|INTEREST_POST_ID|USER_POST_ID|INTEREST|
+----------------+------------+--------+
|               1|           1|   1,2,3|
```

Comment: Hi Gourav, I tried your method, it shows null records.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. You can do something like this:

`var result = hiveContext.sql("""SELECT USER_POST_ID
     |   FROM`INTEREST_POST_TABLE
     `|  WHERE INTEREST REGEXP '(?=.*0[1])(?=.*0[2])(?=.*0[3])' """) 
 result.show`

[Fetching Records from INTEREST_POST_TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HJhs.png)